# Why do I get a API level error on this comparator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The documentation states [compare(T o1, T o2) is implemented in API level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)). Yet Android studio gives me an error that the following call requires API level 24.

```
    Queue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return 0; //I know this is not comparing anything.
        }
    });
```

[image]

I need a solution that is not using the object itself for comparing so implementing `Comparable` on the object itself is not what I am looking for. The reason is I need to use additional variables for each group I want to compare and the object itself should not need to know about how it gets sorted.

Comment: The error isn't on the `Comparator`. It's on that particular `PriorityQueue` constructor, which wasn't introduced until API level 24: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Comparator<?%20super%20E>). Use the constructor that takes an `int initialCapacity`, too, as it was introduced in API level 1: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator<?%20super%20E>).

Comment: @Shaman You are right, I was put on the wrong foot by AS and thought it was the Comparator that was creating this error.